# Parse pushes not being sent

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have two perfect devices installations in Parse Core:
[image]

When I'm creating a new push notification (plain text notification), there is information that it will be sent to these two devices:
[image]

But then it isn't sent to any device at all:[image]

The status is success but "Pushes Sent" are zero. Already checked for Parse [service status](https://status.parse.com/) and are up and online.

No information about any pushes in the device's debugging console so I presume that pushes aren't being sent at all.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your are sending Pushes with JSON payload, Android Apps won't get it until you implement a custom broadcast receiver class and override onReceive method. With default receiver app should be able to receive Pushes with text only. This is what I faced in my app.

Comment: Not sending a push with JSON payload. Only sent with plain text.

Comment: Than re check the procedure of how you have initialized Parse in your android app, re check all manifest modifications that Parse requires to work properly. As shown here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing If the device is restarted Parse won't start working until you open the app once! You should be missing a small detail I guess...

Comment: Parse is well initialized: there are installations registered as you can see in the images provided in question. I have the same implementation in several other apps which successfully receive pushes from Parse. Here the problem is that those pushes don't leave Parse services at all.