# In parse, pushes sent is always 0

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

For all push notifications that I've tried sending, the status is always "Succeeded" but none have arrived on any device.

In my parse dashboard, the installations are not empty (there are 5).

"Client Push Enabled" is set to "Yes" (tried sending both with Yes and No).

I have tried sending through parse dashboard and through django. I have tried targeting "everyone" and "channels". In all cases the status is green but "Pushes Sent" is 0.

This question has been asked a couple of times but none of the answers are working for me.

Here is the question with the closest situation to mine: [Parse pushes not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339745/parse-pushes-not-being-sent)
This question however, was also not answered.

Comment: if you could give us some more information like some code or some more detail so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

I have also face this issue.
The reason of 0 recipients as push sent is because in present case the push is never sent to any of the recipient although you are seeing entries in the installation table.

Reason: deviceToken field must be missing in your case.

If there are installation entries in the table but all these entries are missing deviceToken then parse will not send push notification because that deviceToken is mandatory.

You have to add following permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

along with parse related code you have to add the following code for GCM so that parse can get deviceToken:

```
<permission
    android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="your.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but the entries in my Installations table all have deviceTokens set and I've confirmed that they are accurate.